# How to get the finger print result with-out authenticating from Fingerprint-manager?

Tags: java, android, fingerprint, android-fingerprint-api

I want to use the fingerprint scanner(default in android M device), **but I don't want to use any authentication**, I just want to take the result of the finger and send that result to middle-ware.Is it possible with the default fingerprint scanner or any library to return the unique finger results.

In Middle-ware they will store the result based on the finger results and do process based on the results.If it possible with any library let me know.

Comment: No, vendors are strictly protecting that data (besides it undermines the whole purpose if you sent it over the network)

Comment: if it was possible to scan fingerprint without authentication, then you could easily steal user's fingerprint. For example you continuously scan fingerprint all the time, and once user wants to approve something with his fingerprint, you get it too. For that reason you can't.

Comment: @VladMatvienko is there any unique id for one finger instead of the fingerprint data.I don't want any data(regarding to the fingerprint data), I want unique id for finger, is it possible?

Comment: may I know the why it is downvoted, is it not understandably or not useful.Please write comment before downvoting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you cannot. As far as i know there is no way or an api for doing this. The main idea of this is to keep the `fingerprint` protected and not to share it over an network.

Hope it helps.

Comment: you mean say that it will be locally for that device only, we can't get any data from the result, it will be used for only authentication, right?